# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations filter on bundleId or packageId

Tags: graph, filter, odata, power-automate, microsoft-graph-intune

I am trying to retrieve info from *intune* via *GraphApi*.

Want to filter on `bundleId` or `packageId` field (located under appIdentifier).
But I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Target result is :

> userId,os_type (based on either @odata.type or packageId/bundleId).

Step further is that i want to identify certain apps by filtering on for example `startswith(packageId,'com.microsoft')`.

I have tried combinations on `"/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations?$filter=startswith(bundleId,'com.m')`. But I keep on ending up on "`invalid filter clause`" whenever i want to execute a filter action.

Trying to recover from microsoft documentation if any filtering is possible on this part of graph seems impossible.

Currently we are using power automate to retrieve data and that works if we don't filter / select.

[screenshot of json result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqpmh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following filter: `startsWith(microsoft.graph.iosVppApp/bundleId, 'com.microsoft')`

I found a pointer at this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Intune/comments/cxkwm3/using_graph_to_show_all_apps_from_one_vpp_token/

Comment: Wow great find ! THANKS Francois